# Algorithm used by Mathematica for evaluating partial sums

Tags: special-functions, summation, implementation-details

Today, while using mathematica, I entered the command `Sum[1/Factorial[n], {n, 0, x}]` and found that:
$$\sum_{x\geq n\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{e\Gamma(x+1,1)}{\Gamma(x+1)}$$
Where $\Gamma(x,y)$ is the [Incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
It is well known that
$$\sum_{x\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}=e$$
But which algorithm(or formula) did Mathematica use? If the algorithm is too complex for human use, how can we prove the first equality?
Another result it gave was
$$\sum_{m\geq n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\,n!}=\frac{(\mathrm{Ei}(1)-\gamma)m(m+1)!+(\mathrm{Ei}(1)-\gamma)(m+1)!-_2F_2(1,m+1;m+2,m+2;1)}{(m+1)(m+1)!}$$
Where $\mathrm{Ei}$ is the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) and $F$ is the [Generalized hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/). This looks very hard to evaluate by hand, is there any formula or algorithm to evaluate this? I shouldn't say this on MSE, but I don't know how to do this, I can't do even a step.

Comment: I don't know how Mathematica finds these sums, but they look they that can be found with the [Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair). In particular, we can write the first sum as `E - Sum[1/(n + x + 1)!, {n, 0, ∞}]`.

Comment: In fact these sums can be readily expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions by rewriting the summands. For example, $$\frac{1}{(n+x+1)!} = \frac{(1)_n}{\Gamma (x+2) n! (x+2)_n}$$ and so $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n+x+1)!} = \frac{\, _1F_1(1;x+2;1)}{\Gamma (x+2)}.$$

Comment: @chipHurst: thanks for your comment. I solved both the sums.

Comment: Why do you write, "I shouldn't say this on MSE, but I don't know how to do this"? Speaking just for myself, I am not very good at solving mathematical problems, but I've been enjoying the many uses of Mathematica for nine years. This software helps me solve math problems, as well as some other problems that are not mainly about math.

Comment: @ralphDratman:I have seen many questions containing "I don't have any idea" or "I don't know a thing" get downvotes.